# Global(system) hotkeys for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create system hotkeys/shortcuts for Google Chrome Extension? I mean hotkeys that also works when Chrome doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it won't be trivial. To get truly global hotkeys you will have to use [native messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging). You will need to create some application to run in the background and capture keypresses and then you can send those keypresses back to Chrome through stdout. This approach will require you to create an additional installer for your extension to install the native messaging app onto the user's system...before you could bundle your app along with the extension (using NPAPI) but that has recently been phased out. I have seen some discussion in the Chromium group about adding bundling support for native messaging apps, but nothing has been added (yet).

Another much easier option is to use the Chrome commands API which will enable you to use hotkeys across all Chrome windows (but not globally...). Just something to consider if "true" global hotkeys are not an absolute requirement since this approach is (much) less complex.

Global media keys will be added to Chrome soon, however. There is a good discussion about this feature to read [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131612).

Answer (score -1):

It's now part of Chrome: `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`